# Is cassandra table locked while doing truncate operation

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to truncate a Cassandra table every scheduled interval of time, but i am not sure if the table gets locked while performing truncate? 
That is, what will happen to other insert operation waiting to be performed?
Does it store it temporarily while the truncate is in progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the TTL for the column data and expiring it after a certain period of time:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the article really helped a lot. Sorry for delayed response, as i somehow missed the notification for the reply :)